# Combobox trigger empty selection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, triggers

I have a combobox. When the selection is empty (the selection is binding from the model) I want to change the combobox text to unsupported.

I put the following style on the combobox:

```
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="unsupported"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

And still when the selected index is -1 the text remains empty (I check it with snoop).

(I also tried to use `SelectedValue = null`).

Does someone know what the problem is (I dont have any problem with the binding, I check it on the output window & on the snoop).

Comment: Did you set `IsEditable="True"`?

Comment: No. but if I set it, it works on the same way. it is not slove the problem

Answer (score 0):

I checked your XAML and it worked for me! You really have to set `IsEditable="True"`. Unfortunately the style of the Combobox changes.